# Add a icon on selected date in NGB Calendar

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap datepicker to display calender in my app inline calendar, the calendar does not display a curent day icon like this.

[image]

Any idea for this? I tried with so many times but I was unable to find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#today) will help!

> You can completely replace how each date is rendered by providing a custom template and rendering anything you want inside. You'll get a date context available inside the template with info on whether current date is disabled, selected, focused, etc.

> For more info on what is provided in the template context, see the DayTemplateContext API

Do the follow:

```
<ngb-datepicker
            [dayTemplate]="t"
            #d1
            [formControl]="reactModel"
            [startDate]="model2"
            (dateSelect)="datePicked($event)"
          >
            <ng-template #t let-date>
              <button>{{ date.day }}</button>
            </ng-template>
          </ngb-datepicker>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcktw8-7iobaq?file=src/app/popover-tplcontent.html) is the Stackblitz.